# impala/hive show file format

Tags: hive, hdfs, impala

How can I have impala or hive return the file format of the underlying files on HDFS for a table?

I tried:

```sql
SHOW FILES database.table_name
```

This ilst the files, but the problem is that some people stored parquet files as `.parq` and others `.parquet`. Is there anyway to return the file format, such that one could use it in a new create statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use good old `show create table mytable`.
You can check the output and it clearly mentions file format. It also shows folder inside which file are stored - you should not try to use file name - let impala decide the name. below is a sample result from impala.

```
result  
CREATE TABLE edh.mytable (
  column1 STRING
 )
STORED AS PARQUET  --file format
LOCATION 's3a://cc-mys3/edh/user/hive/warehouse/edh.db/mytable' --folder location
```